# Create Trigger to modify a row to the value on a joined table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a tables job_costcodes(id, cost_code_no, dept_id) and cost_codes(code_code_no, dept_id).

I am trying to make it so if `job_costcodes.cost_code_no` is modified, `job_costcodes.dept_id` is filled with the appropriate one from the `cost_codes` table, based on a matching `code_code_no`.

So referring to the tables below, if the top row in job_costcodes is changed to 10, the dept_id should change to 1212. Or 20 to 1313, etc.

[image]

I am not sure exactly how the syntax works... here is what I have so far.
UPDATE: updated code.. i think it works now.

```
create trigger update_test on dbo.job_costcodes
for update, insert
as
begin
 set nocount on

 update dbo.job_costcodes
 set dept_id = (select CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 THEN MIN(dbo.cost_codes.dept_id) ELSE NULL END as Expr1
                FROM inserted INNER JOIN
                     dbo.cost_codes ON dbo.cost_codes.cost_code_no = inserted.cost_code_no)
from inserted as i
inner join dbo.[job_costcodes] on dbo.[job_costcodes].id = i.id

end
```

Comment: Your trigger has two MAJOR flaws. First is that you seem to assume there will only ever be a single row updated. Triggers is sql server fire once per operation, not once per row. Second major flaw is you are not using either the inserted or deleted virtual tables. The whole structure of the way you started here is not what you want. I can't really tell you how to fix it because I don't really know what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I am trying to make it so if job_costcodes.cost_code_no is modified, job_costcodes.dept_id is filled with the appropriate one from the cost_codes table, based on a matching code_code_no

Comment: I could answer your question, but seriously, fix your database design before you make even more problems for yourself.   Why even have dept_id in the job_cc table, if you can simply look it up in the cost_code table???   Normalize your data!   Using a trigger for this is a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: Can you post some table definitions so we have something to work with? http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ This is a fairly straight forward update query but not entirely sure what you want.

Comment: I fully agree with you, Tab. But these are the tables that were set up for a POS software my company decided to buy. I cannot go around modifying table structures or else the software will not work correctly. Our only option here is to use a trigger or manually input the information. And yes, Sean, I will update my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treating your question as academic, start off by looking up the CREATE TRIGGER command in TSQL to get a solid understanding of the virtual tables `inserted` and `deleted`.

Then here is what I would do, in pseudo-cod-ish descriptive terms:

In your trigger, simply UPDATE `job_costcodes` and set the value of `dept_id` to the corresponding `dept_id` in `cost_codes` by JOINing to `cost_codes` and `inserted` in the FROM clause of the UPDATE.

There is no need to verify that the `cost_code_no` changed when doing this, the result will be the same, but if you feel you must do this, then look at the IF UPDATE() function in TSQL.  You can then compare the value of `cost_code_no` in `inserted` vs `deleted` to know if it changed at all.